# Binding data to slider doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, slider

I've got a problem with a binding in my windows phone project.  I'm binding an class to a slider, but it won't update the value.  If I first start the app, the binding connection is established correctly and the slider does have its correct value.  But if I change the "position" or "duration" value, the slider won't update with it.

Can you please help me? I don't have any clue, what I'm doing wrong :(

Class.cs:

```
public class Status : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void PropChanged(string propName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
  }

  public double duration
  {
    get { return _duration; }
    set
    {
      if (this._duration == value)
        return;

      _duration = value;
      PropChanged("duration");
    }
  }

  public double position
  {
    get { return _position; }
    set
    {
      if (this._position == value)
        return;

      _position = value;
      PropChanged("position");
    }
  }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  public MainPage()
  {
    this.ContentPanel.DataContext = _Status;
  }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
 ...
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,12,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Slider x:Name="sl_PlayBackProgress"
            Value="{Binding Path=position}"
            Maximum="{Binding Path=duration}"
            Height="91"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="0,40,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="408"/>
</Grid>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if it different from normal XAML/WPF. But in normal case I would recommend first to set up [Binding.Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx) to TwoWay and next just break on position.set entrance - and see the passed `value`

Comment: Setting the Binding.Mode to 'TwoWay' didn't make any changes. Also the 'position' variable is updated correctly.
I think it is a problem with the binding itself. If i manually set the 'Maximum' properties to an static value, the slider updates correctly. Is it possible, that can't have binding on both properties?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry i have to correct myself. I've overread the TwoWay and set it straigth to "OneWay"... My fault, sorry!

But can you please explain to me, why i have to set this to 'TwoWay'? As far as i understand, i do an 'OneWay' Binding.